# Parent the model to the rigify error

Tags: error, rigify

When I parent my model to a *Rigify* rig, I get these deformations:

[image]

[image]

Here is a video of the steps taken: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttt0-aabLQY

Comment: Hi, Pumpkin, if my edits don't reflect your question properly, please revise them.. give folks as much info as you can, in the post, to help them help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try applying all rotations, location to deltas, and scales

Answer (score 0):

Before parenting models to a rig:

1. Apply both models' and rig's scale in object mode:
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Scale
2. Remove any pose from the rig by either:

   - entering pose mode and using <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.
   - Properties Editor > Armature tab > set it frome Pose to Rest Pose.